# Sidekiq and concurrency of a single queue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, sidekiq

I have 3 Queues running

```
User
Follower
Default
```

The User can import his Data which is then done by the `User` queue. 
That actually creates tons of followers (up to millions) and each of them is having an after_create to update theirself, in the `Follower` queue.

The Problem here is, that 50 Users can create their imports right now, but i want only 1 import to be done at the same time. First in First out - while the `Follower-Queue` should be still working with 100 simultanously workers.
example: 1 user imports 500.000 followers. then the next user imports 5 million. the next imports 400. meanwhile the followers of user 1 are loaded.

is it possible to do?

my YAML looks like this

```
:queues:
  - user
  - follower
  - default
```

the docs are telling me now, that the user queue is high prioritized. but how to tell that only 1 job from this queue is done at the same time?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This feature is **not supported by the sidekiq core** (and the author [does not want to add](https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/issues/200#issuecomment-6378852) such feature to it). However, there is an external middleware that seems to support setting worker limits per queue, the **[`sidekiq-limit_fetch` gem](https://github.com/brainopia/sidekiq-limit_fetch#limits)**. Using it you should be able to easily set what you need:

```
# sidekiq.yml
:limits:
  user: 1
  follower: 100
  default: 10 # or whatever you like
```

The gem code is a little older though, you mileage may vary...

Comment: sweet. i saw it already but then clicked away. i'll give it a try :-)